# Adding in a for loop messes up my calculations when finding the average of 2 lists of numbers. Anyone have a good solution?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, i, input_cases,x;
    float num[100], sum[2] = {0.0}, average[2] = {0.0};

    //scanf("%d", &input_cases);
    //for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++){

    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validate your input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1) { /* validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* sum/average 1st-half */
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
        sum[0] += num[i];
    average[0] = sum[0] * 2 / n;

    /* sum/average 2nd-half */
    for (i = n/2; i < n; ++i)
        sum[1] += num[i];
    average[1] = sum[1] * 2 / n;
    if (average[0]>average[1]){
                printf("%.6lf\n", average[0]);
                }
        else{
            printf("%.6lf\n", average[1]);}

    //}
    return 0;
}
```

So what this code does is it reads in a list of numbers, splits up that list in half, finds the average of the two split up lists, and then tells you the highest average out of the two lists. For example:

```
Input: 
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11
```

Output:

```
10.800000
```

What I'm trying to do is perform this operation multiple times. So say I want to do this with 2 different lists. My program should give me the 2 highest averages of the 2 different lists. I've added in a for loop to try and make that happen but somewhere in between the loop, my highest average for my second number list gets messed up and I can't seem to figure out where. I've commented out my for loop to show you guys that doing it without a loop works perfectly. It's only when I add the for loop in that my calculations become messed up. With the for loop, this is what shows:

Input:

```
2  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  
10.800000(This is the result)  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 4    
3  
3  
2  
1  
30.000000 (This should be 3.000000)
```

What I WANT it to show:

```
Input:  
2  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 4    
3  
3  
2  
1  

Output:  
10.800000  
3.000000
```

Comment: `sum[(i*2)/n] +=num[i];`. That is wrong even without the commented out `for` loop. Because `sum` is not initialized. So it contains random garbage and thus is Undefined Behaviour to use it. The fact that it "works" for the single test case is by accident and cannot be relied on. Fix that, by zeroing out `sum` at the start of each test case loop, and you'll probably find the multiple test case will work as well.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I simply moved my variable declarations right under my main for loop.